# Is list join really faster than string concatenation in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, bytecode

I find that string concatenation seems to have less python bytecode than list join.

This is an example.

test.py:

```
a = ''.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])
b = 'a' + 'b' + 'c'
```

Then I execute `python -m dis test.py`.
I got the following python bytecode (python 2.7):

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 ('')
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (join)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a')
              9 LOAD_CONST               2 ('b')
             12 LOAD_CONST               3 ('c')
             15 BUILD_LIST               3
             18 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             21 STORE_NAME               1 (a)

  3          24 LOAD_CONST               6 ('abc')
             27 STORE_NAME               2 (b)
             30 LOAD_CONST               4 (None)
             33 RETURN_VALUE
```

Obviously, the bytecode number of string concatenation is less.It just load string `'abc'` directly.

Can anyone explain why we always say that list join is much better?

Comment: Because you don't always know beforehand which strings you are going to concatenate. Using `+`, or using `sum()` on many strings you don't know beforehand eventually results in a quadratic runtime, as opposed to `.join` which is optimized.

Comment: It is going to vary on use-case. But overall, yes.  See http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string/

Comment: Note that `b='a' + 'b' + 'c'` is taking advantage of constant folding, since all three operands are known at compile time. Try something like `b = a1 + a2 + a3`, and you'll see more complex byte code generated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[From Efficient String Concatenation in Python](https://web.archive.org/web/20120902083755/http://www.skymind.com/%7Eocrow/python_string)

`Method 1` : 'a' + 'b' + 'c'

`Method 6` :  a = ''.join(['a', 'b', 'c'])

20,000 integers were concatenated into a string 86kb long :

[image: pic]

> ```
>                 Concatenations per second     Process size (kB)
>   Method 1               3770                    2424
>   Method 6               119,800                 3000
> ```

**Conclusion : YES**, `str.join()` is **significantly faster** then typical concatenation (`str1+str2`).

Comment: The link is dead

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20120902083755/http://www.skymind.com/~ocrow/python_string

Comment: The current URL is: https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/

Answer (score 5):

Don't believe it! Always get proof!

Source: I stared at python source code for an hour and calculated complexities!

My findings.

For 2 strings. (Assume n is the length of both strings)

```
Concat (+) - O(n)
Join - O(n+k) effectively O(n)
Format - O(2n+k) effectively O(n)
```

For more than 2 strings. (Assume n is the length of all strings)

```
Concat (+) - O(n^2)
Join - O(n+k) effectively O(n)
Format - O(2n+k) effectively O(n)
```

RESULT:

If you have two strings technically concatenation (+) is better, effectively though it is exactly the same as join and format.

If you have more than two strings concat becomes awful and join and format are effectively the same though technically join is a bit better.

SUMMARY:

If you don't care for efficiency use any of the above. (Though since you asked the question I would assume you care)

Therefore -

If you have 2 strings use concat (when not in a loop!)
If you have more than two strings (all strings) (or in a loop) use join
If you have anything not strings use format, because duh.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 3):

Because

```
''.join(my_list)
```

is much better than

```
my_list[0] + my_list[1]
```

and better than

```
my_list[0] + my_list[1] + my_list[2]
```

and better than

```
my_list[0] + my_list[1] + my_list[2] + my_list[3]
```

and better…

In short:

```
print 'better than'
print ' + '.join('my_list[{}]'.format(i) for i in xrange(x))
```

for any `x`.