# String addition in Python really slower than using join?

Tags: python, string, performance

This question refers to [Is list join really faster than string concatenation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147344/is-list-join-really-faster-than-string-concatenation-in-python) and https://waymoot.org/home/python_string/

I wanted to demo that using `+` for concatentating strings is really slower than using `"".join(...)`. But somehow I failed:

```
%%timeit
result = ""
for i in range(3000000):
    result = result + 100 * str(i)

3.28 s ± 46.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

And

```
%%timeit
result = []

for i in range(3000000):
    result.append(100 * str(i))

result = "".join(result)

4.34 s ± 116 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

I'm using `Python 3.6` and my assumption is that recent versions optimize string addition. Any comments on this ?

Comment: I'm confused. You wanted to benchmark the concatenation, correct? Why do you also time the generation of input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that you were not being fair in your comparison. Particularly in your second snippet you make the mistake of also timing the creation of the strings to join. The append will probably dominate there.

First we create the elements to join.

```
strings = []

for i in range(3000000):
    strings.append(100 * str(i))
```

Timing string concatenation

```
%%timeit
result = ''
for i in strings:
   result = result + i

1.65 s ± 23.3 ms per loop
```

Now timing the join method

```
%timeit result = ''.join(strings)

571 ms ± 10.3 ms per loop
```

Thus, it holds true the statement that join is faster than concatenating!

Comment: I see. The conclusion for me is that using `append` + `join` can be slower than `+` and the snippets I compared are quite realistic use cases. Which means I can not always favor `join` over `+`.

Comment: It's not the same. As I said, you are also doing an append which is very expensive as it has to every now and then create a bigger list (allocate memory) and then copy the old list. In the first snippet you create each element of the fly. Thus, you end up timing two different things.

Comment: Did not say that is the same. But I have practical use cases where people introduce as `list` and use  `append` and `join` because they were told that this is faster. So you'd only benefit from `join` if you already have a list of strings to get started.

Comment: Sure, what people use is another issue. But hte question and statement is regarding to the operation concatenation vs join.